# Projectile code reports wrong number of arguments

Tags: game-maker

I'm not certain as to why my code isn't working. The error reports that the `instance_create` line uses a wrong number of arguments. What am I doing wrong?

```
if(ammo > 0)
{
    ammo -= 1;

    bullet_id = instance_create(
        x + lengthdir_x(lenx, image_angle) - lengthdir_y(leny, image.angle),
        y + lengthdir_y(lenx, image_angle) + lengthdir_x(leny, image_angle));

    bullet_id.direction = image_angle;
    bullet_id.image_angle = bullet_id.direction
```

Comment: Please note that it is *significantly* easier to help with code that is written as text. You will find a lot of users simply won't bother with a screenshot. Given your code was very minimal, I transcribed it for you. *I believe this question is off-topic*, as you are having a *syntax* problem. These issues are generic to programming, and as such, they are usually directed to StackOverflow.

Comment: As Tom points out, [documentation](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/objects%20and%20instances/instances/instance%20functions/instance_create.html) clearly states that `instance_create` takes ***3*** arguments; You are supplying the `x` and `y` (positions, I presume). You are *not* supplying the `obj`, which I assume is reference of some sort to the *object* you are trying to create.

Comment: Perhaps your problem may come in understanding *where you should get* that original `obj` reference. If so, I would recommend editing your question to ask *how* you should be using `instance_create`, given the context you provide in your current question.

Comment: One vvery last thing, in transcribing I noted that you had not closed your `if` loop by adding `}` at the end of the logic. *This is bad. Very, very bad*. In many cases, this problem can actually *confuse* your compiler, and lead to a whole bunch of random errors just like the one you report, due to the *compiler* mis-interpretting everything. It is clear that this is a legitimate error, but make sure you ensure closing brackets, in the future. It might solve a few errors that would otherwise be hard to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the Game Maker API, but [I believe](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/objects%20and%20instances/instances/instance%20functions/instance_create.html) you're missing the third argument in the `instance_create` method.

```
instance_create(x, y, obj);
```

Comment: Definitely the issue the user is having. Please consider the comments I have made on the original question. Should the user change the question as per my suggestion, you might want to ensure your answer still addresses the actual concern (I believe the user does not know *where* to get `obj` from)